# Event firing Twice in IE onclick and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have a page with 2 text box and 2 buttons and 2 form to wrap the textbox and button pair. When user types something and click or submit enter the event is sent twice and this only **happens in IE**. Based on the event firing the integration layer a request is sent twice, which is not suppose to happen. I really can't see  in the javascript code that request is sent twice (I tried to sysout the request but it print only once). I really can't see the event is happening twice  and how can I see the event happening twice.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function grabKeyword(){
   var search=document.getElementById('search_box_second').value;
   search=encodeSearch(search);
   document.forms['Form1'].Term.value = search;
   document.forms['Form1'].submit();
   }

function submitSecondSearch(e)
{

if(window.event)
      keycode = window.event.keyCode; // IE
else           
      keycode = e.which;
      
      
if (keycode == 13)
   {
  grabKeyword();
   }
else
   {
   return true;
   }
}
 
</script>

<form action="/" style="" method="post" name="Form1" id="Form1">
<input id="search_box_second" class="search_results_input" type="text"  onKeyDown="submitSecondSearch(event)" /></span>
      <span style="float:right"><input type="image" src="images/bttn_search_result.png" value="submit" onClick="grabKeyword()" /></span>

<input type="hidden" name="page" value="Page" />
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action" />
 <input type="hidden" name="Term" value="" />
</form>

This is one form. i have another form in same page.

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 function grabSearch(){
    var search=document.getElementById('search_box').value;
    search=encodeSearch(search);
    document.forms['Form'].Term.value = search;
    document.forms['Form'].submit();
 }
 function encodeSearch(term){
    return term.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g," ");
 }
 </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 function submitenter(e)
{
if(window.event)
      keycode = window.event.keyCode; // IE
else
      keycode = e.which;
      
if (keycode == 13)
   {
  grabSearch();
   }
else
{
   return true;
   }
}
</script>

<form action="/" style="" method="post" name="Form" id="Form"><input id="search_box" type="text" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onKeyDown="submitenter(event)" />
    <div id="search_arrow"><input type="image" src="/images/search_arrow.png" width="4" height="8" value="submit" onClick="grabSearch()" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="Page" />
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action" />
 <input type="hidden" name="Term" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="image" src="images/bttn_search_result.png" value="submit" onClick="grabKeyword(); return false;" />
```

Comment: how can we debug that 2 event are being fired. i did the alert way. but i am not catching it. is their any efficient way that we can see this.Also this only happen in IE

Comment: WHat worked for me is that i removed all the onclick and onkeypress and i had simple form onsubmit. So that fixed the bug. Crazy IE

Answer (score 7):

You should try a

```
return false;
```

after your .submit();
This way the default behaviour of the image input element gets omitted.

Comment: document.forms['Form1'].submit();return false; like this